# Getting Issue in Solr Search with DSE

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am using DSE version = 5.0.1 . Using Solr for Search activities. I created core successfully for particular table. 
After that once I am trying to execute solr seach query , I am getting below issue :-

---

cqlsh:tradebees_dev> SELECT * FROM yf_product_books where solr_query = '*:*';

```
ServerError: <Error from server: code=0000 [Server error]
 message="java.io.IOException: 
No shards available for ranges: [(2205014674981121837,2205014674981121837]]">
```

Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this : -

SELECT * FROM yf_product_books where solr_query = '*:*';